# Centring table cell content under headers/subheaders

Tags: tables

How may I place `cell1`, `cell4` and `cell7` under the `particle` column and `cell2`, `cell5` and `cell8` under the `mass` column in `family 1`?

```
    \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage{blindtext}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \DeclareMathOperator{\sgn}{sgn}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{c c c}
Family 1 & Family 2 & Family 3\\
Particle \hspace{2em} Mass & Particle \hspace{2em} Mass & Particle \hspace{2em} Mass\\
\hline
cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\
\hline
cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\  
\hline
cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: And are `cell3`, `cell6`, `cell9` under what?

Comment: How may I fill all the other columns by cell3, cell6 and cell9?

Comment: I have tided up the comment thread here and tried to make the title more general.

Comment: @JosephWright Thank you very much for the improvement, Joseph! Next time a question is asked, I shall make sure I will make a title. I appreciate it very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define 6 columns and change `\tabcolsep` to `1em`

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sgn}{sgn}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1em}
\begin{tabular}{*{6}{c}}
Family 1 & Family 2 & Family 3\\
Particle & Mass & Particle & Mass & Particle & Mass\\
\hline
cell1 & & cell2 & & cell3 \\
\hline
cell4 && cell5 && cell6 \\
\hline
cell7 && cell8 && cell9 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]